# Python: Imported Tkinter program runs itself?

Tags: python, import, tkinter, window, runtime

So I'm writing a program for my final year project, and this thing in particular has just been bugging the hell out of me. I've been at it so long and I can't figure it out, so I'm hoping somebody fresh will be able to shed some light on it!

Basically, my program is for recording and storing results for my school's sports day. The idea is that it will actually be used in the future by the school, so I want it to be aesthetic as well as functional. Of course, this means integrating a UI of some kind, and since I've used Tkinter before it seemed like the obvious approach.

So far I've just got the basic windows coded. I have two windows: a main window and an "edit" window for changing participant names. I've written the code for these two windows in separate *.py* files and imported the "*edit*" window file into the main file, so that I can call for it to run when an "*EDIT*" button is clicked in the main window. For whatever reason, however, the "*edit*" window simply runs itself when I run the main program, even though the only reference to it is `import editWindow`.

**This is the code for the main window:**

```
'''
Created on 19 Jan 2015

@author: James.D.Wood
'''

#!/usr/bin/env python

#init
from tkinter import *
import editWindow

global event, year, cr, sr, a1, a2, s1, s2, d1, d2, n1, n2, ar1, ar2, sr1, sr2, dr1, dr2, nr1, nr2, msg, b, s, g

events = [
          "70m hurdles",
          "75m hurdles",
          "80m hurdles",
          "100m hurdles",          
          "100m",
          "200m",
          "300m",
          "400m",
          "800m",
          "1500m",
          "Javelin",
          "Long-jump",
          "High-jump",
          "Triple-jump",
          "Shot-put",
          "Discus",
          "Relay"
          ]
years = [
         "7",
         "8",
         "9",
         "10",
         "11",
         "12",
         "13"
         ]


#create/define window
    #main win
win = Tk()
win.title("Queens' Athletics")

win.minsize(800,600)
win.maxsize(800,600)


    #section 1
event = StringVar() #event var
event.set("Select event...") #default
year = StringVar() #year var
year.set("Select year...") #default
lineImg = PhotoImage(file="resources/line.gif", master=win) #load separator image

sel = Label(win, text="Select event:")
slctEvnt = OptionMenu(win, event, *events) #dropdown box
slctEvnt.config(width=20)
selYr = Label(win, text="Select year:")
slctYr = OptionMenu(win, year, *years) #dropdown box
slctYr.config(width=20)
line = Label(win, image=lineImg) #separator
line.image = lineImg

#pack into window
sel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
slctEvnt.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=4, sticky=W)
selYr.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
slctYr.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=4, sticky=W)
line.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=W, pady=15)


    #section 2
cr = StringVar() #county record var
cr.set(" - ") #default
sr = StringVar() #school record var
sr.set(" - ") #default

crl = Label(win, text="County record:")
crBox = Label(win, width=6, textvariable=cr, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg="grey") #county record box
srl = Label(win, text="School record:")
srBox = Label(win, width=6, textvariable=sr, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg="grey") #school record box

#pack into window
crl.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
crBox.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, padx=10)
srl.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W)
srBox.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=W, padx=10)


    #section 3
#participant names
a1 = StringVar()
a1.set(". . .") #default
a2 = StringVar()
a2.set(". . .") #default
s1 = StringVar()
s1.set(". . .") #default
s2 = StringVar()
s2.set(". . .") #default
d1 = StringVar()
d1.set(". . .") #default
d2 = StringVar()
d2.set(". . .") #default
n1 = StringVar()
n1.set(". . .") #default
n2 = StringVar()
n2.set(". . .") #default
#results
ar1 = StringVar()
ar2 = StringVar()
sr1 = StringVar()
sr2 = StringVar()
dr1 = StringVar()
dr2 = StringVar()
nr1 = StringVar()
nr2 = StringVar()
#
vLineImg = PhotoImage(file="resources/vline.gif", master=win) #load separator image

blank1 = Label(win, text="") #blank separator
part = Label(win, text="Students participating:")
resul = Label(win, text="      Results")
#participant names
auden1 = Label(win, width=36, textvariable=a1, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg="yellow")
auden2 = Label(win, width=36, textvariable=a2, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg="yellow")
suthe1 = Label(win, width=36, textvariable=s1, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg="blue")
suthe2 = Label(win, width=36, textvariable=s2, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg="blue")
drake1 = Label(win, width=36, textvariable=d1, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg="green")
drake2 = Label(win, width=36, textvariable=d2, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg="green")
newto1 = Label(win, width=36, textvariable=n1, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg="red")
newto2 = Label(win, width=36, textvariable=n2, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg="red")
#results
auRes1 = Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=ar1, justify=CENTER, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg="yellow")
auRes2 = Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=ar2, justify=CENTER, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg="yellow")
suRes1 = Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=sr1, justify=CENTER, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg="blue")
suRes2 = Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=sr2, justify=CENTER, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg="blue")
drRes1 = Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=dr1, justify=CENTER, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg="green")
drRes2 = Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=dr2, justify=CENTER, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg="green")
neRes1 = Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=nr1, justify=CENTER, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg="red")
neRes2 = Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=nr2, justify=CENTER, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg="red")
#
vLine = Label(win, image=vLineImg)
vLine.image = vLineImg

#pack into window
blank1.grid(row=5)
part.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W, pady=8)
resul.grid(row=7, column=3, sticky=W)
#participant names
auden1.grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W, padx=8)
auden2.grid(row=9, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W, padx=8)
suthe1.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W, padx=8)
suthe2.grid(row=11, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W, padx=8)
drake1.grid(row=12, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W, padx=8)
drake2.grid(row=13, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W, padx=8)
newto1.grid(row=14, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W, padx=8)
newto2.grid(row=15, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W, padx=8)
#results
auRes1.grid(row=8, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
auRes2.grid(row=9, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
suRes1.grid(row=10, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
suRes2.grid(row=11, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
drRes1.grid(row=12, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
drRes2.grid(row=13, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
neRes1.grid(row=14, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
neRes2.grid(row=15, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
#
vLine.grid(row=8, column=4, rowspan=8, sticky=W, padx=35)


    #section 4
msg = StringVar()
msg.set("[                ]")

edit = Button(win, width=8, text="Edit >", padx=15, pady=8)
submit = Button(win, width=8, text="Submit >", padx=15, pady=8)
msgBox = Message(win, textvariable=msg, anchor=CENTER, justify=CENTER, aspect=200, borderwidth=2, relief='ridge', bg='grey')
reset = Button(win, width=8, text="Reset >", padx=15, pady=8)

#pack into window
edit.grid(row=16, column=1, rowspan=2, sticky=S, pady=12)
submit.grid(row=16, column=3, rowspan=2, sticky=S, pady=12)
msgBox.grid(row=16, column=4, rowspan=2, columnspan=3, sticky=S, pady=16)
reset.grid(row=16, column=7, rowspan=2, sticky=S, pady=12)


    #section 5
img = PhotoImage(file="resources/logo.gif", master=win)

logo = Label(win, image=img)
logo.image = img

logo.grid(row=0, column=4, rowspan=7, columnspan=4, sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=60, pady=5)


    #section 6
#leading participants
b = StringVar()
b.set(". . .") #default
s = StringVar()
s.set(". . .") #default
g = StringVar()
g.set(". . .") #default

stand = Label(win, text="Current standing:")
first = Label(win, text="1st")
secon = Label(win, text="2nd")
third = Label(win, text="3rd")
#leading participants
bron = Label(win, width=20, height=2, textvariable=b, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg="brown")
silv = Label(win, width=20, height=2, textvariable=s, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg="lightgrey")
gold = Label(win, width=20, height=2, textvariable=g, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg="gold")

#pack into window
stand.grid(row=7, column=5, rowspan=2, columnspan=3, sticky=E, padx=50)
first.grid(row=9, column=4, rowspan=2, sticky=E, padx=2)
secon.grid(row=11, column=4, rowspan=2, sticky=E, padx=2)
third.grid(row=13, column=4, rowspan=2, sticky=E, padx=2)
#leading participants
bron.grid(row=9, column=5, rowspan=2, columnspan=3, sticky=E, padx=22)
silv.grid(row=11, column=5, rowspan=2, columnspan=3, sticky=E, padx=22)
gold.grid(row=13, column=5, rowspan=2, columnspan=3, sticky=E, padx=22)


win.mainloop()
```

**...And the code for the "*edit*" window:**

```
'''
Created on 29 Jan 2015

@author: James.D.Wood
'''

#!/usr/bin/env python

#init
from tkinter import *

global whichEvent, ea1, ea2, es1, es2, ed1, ed2, en1, en2

#create/define window
    #edit window
Tk().withdraw()
editWin = Toplevel()
editWin.title("Edit participants")

editWin.minsize(350,400)
editWin.maxsize(350,400)


#define elements
whichEvent = StringVar()
whichEvent.set("[EVENT]") #testing
editLineImg = PhotoImage(file="resources/sline.gif", master=editWin)
#edit names boxes
ea1 = StringVar()
ea2 = StringVar()
es1 = StringVar()
es2 = StringVar()
ed1 = StringVar()
ed2 = StringVar()
en1 = StringVar()
en2 = StringVar()

editing = Label(editWin, text="Editing for:")
editEvent = Label(editWin, width=30, textvariable=whichEvent, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg='grey')
editLine = Label(editWin, image=editLineImg) #separator
editLine.image = editLineImg
blank2 = Label(editWin, text="")
blank3 = Label(editWin, text="")
blank4 = Label(editWin, text="")
blank5 = Label(editWin, text="")
#house labels
labAud = Label(editWin, text="Auden:")
labSut = Label(editWin, text="Sutherland:")
labDra = Label(editWin, text="Drake:")
labNew = Label(editWin, text="Newton:")
#edit names boxes
editAud1 = Entry(editWin, width=30, textvariable=ea1, justify=CENTER, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg='yellow')
editAud2 = Entry(editWin, width=30, textvariable=ea2, justify=CENTER, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg='yellow')
editSut1 = Entry(editWin, width=30, textvariable=es1, justify=CENTER, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg='blue')
editSut2 = Entry(editWin, width=30, textvariable=es2, justify=CENTER, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg='blue')
editDra1 = Entry(editWin, width=30, textvariable=ed1, justify=CENTER, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg='green')
editDra2 = Entry(editWin, width=30, textvariable=ed2, justify=CENTER, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg='green')
editNew1 = Entry(editWin, width=30, textvariable=en1, justify=CENTER, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg='red')
editNew2 = Entry(editWin, width=30, textvariable=en2, justify=CENTER, state='normal', relief='sunk', bg='red')

#pack into window
editing.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, pady=15)
editEvent.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W, pady=10)
editLine.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W)
#house labels
blank2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
labAud.grid(row=3, column=0, rowspan=2, sticky=W, pady=10)
blank3.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W)
labSut.grid(row=6, column=0, rowspan=2, sticky=W, pady=10)
blank4.grid(row=8, column=1, sticky=W)
labDra.grid(row=9, column=0, rowspan=2, sticky=W, pady=10)
blank5.grid(row=11, column=1, sticky=W)
labNew.grid(row=12, column=0, rowspan=2, sticky=W, pady=10)
#edit names boxes
editAud1.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
editAud2.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)
editSut1.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W)
editSut2.grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=W)
editDra1.grid(row=9, column=1, sticky=W)
editDra2.grid(row=10, column=1, sticky=W)
editNew1.grid(row=12, column=1, sticky=W)
editNew2.grid(row=13, column=1, sticky=W)
```

I'm at the point now where I'm wondering if it would actually just be better to write the whole program in a single *.py* file, though I thought that doing it this way would be more elegant.

If somebody could suggest a nice, streamlined solution for this that would keep the code for the two windows separate, I would be very grateful. I'm using Python 3.4, FYI.

Thanks.

Comment: you should really be using classes ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All top-level statements in a python module are run when the file is imported.  In your case, because the entirety of your edit file is at the module-level, every statement gets run upon import.  I'd suggest taking your 'edit' commands and putting then inside a function:

```
def run_edit_window():
    ... put your code here
```

Then in your main file, you will import the edit file first:

```
import edit  # Assuming file is named 'edit.py'
```

Then, when your edit button is pressed, call:

```
edit.run_edit_window()
```

Comment: Wow, it was that simple, eh? That's what going days without sleep and still trying to write a program at 1am does to ya! Thanks a bunch, man.

Comment: Good luck with your program!  Programming while tired is always an _interesting_ experience.

Answer (score 5):

When you import a module, you are executing its code. That how importing modules actually works in python. To stop it, put code in the imported module in a function or a class. To be fair, its still being run to make the functions or classes, but they wont be called automatically. They will be just defined. In the main file, you just call the functions/class from the imported module.

Comment: Thanks man, this solved my problem. If I could accept both answers as solutions I would, but sadly I can't.

Comment: @MagickJam:  To make explicit something Marcin hinted at: indented `class` blocks behave the same as modules in this sense.  The class-level code is likewise executed when the interpreter imports the module.  If, for example, you were to put `print` commands in a `class SomeClass:` block (not _inside_ a method, but at the same indent level as all the `def` statements), you would see those lines printed to the console when the class's module gets imported, but not later when the class is instantiated or otherwise used.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase: Ok, thanks, good to know. I hadn't appreciated that code outside of `def` statements is run immediately on import.